# AVD not launching after upgrading android studio and the SDK

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have a problem whenever I try to launch the emulator from Android Studio, after the loading bar finished, the emulator is not showing or starting. This problem occurred after I updated the Android Studio to its latest version. I also tried to update the SDK but no luck, the emulator still won't open. My OS is Windows 10. And my SDK Path is in drive D.

Android Emulator Version : **26.1.4**
Android SDK Tools Version : **26.0.2**
Android Studio Version : **2.3.3**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Blind guess.. Disable Instant Run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Linux, so it's just a guess, but on my platform, I had to add `-use-system-libs` to the start command, so that it looked like this:
`emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -use-system-libs -avd Pixel_API_24`

Don't know if this helps, but maybe it's sth. like this.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is an update available for the emulator system image. If found, please update it.

Another solution is check whether your laptop supports  VTX Technology based on which the recent emulators are developed. This link will help you https://www.technorms.com/8208/check-if-processor-supports-virtualization